# How to add a folder to a folder when creating a zip file in asp using Ionic.Zip

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, dotnetzip

I am able to successfully create a `.zip` file using `AddDirectoryByName` and `AddFile` , my code below :-

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
    zip.AddDirectoryByName("A");
    zip.AddFile("~/.png", "A");
}
```

but what happens is that, it creates a folder by name `A`
and inside it, it adds a file (eg. .png).

But I want to place this folder `A` inside another created folder called "Root", so now how can I create a folder called `Root` to my .zip and add folder `A` to that `Root` ??

Any help thankfully appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the full path name when creating a new directory.

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    string directoryA = "Root/A";
    string directoryB = "Root/B";

    zip.AddEntry($"{directoryA}/readmeA.txt", "Success from Directory A");           
    zip.AddEntry($"{directoryB}/readmeB.txt", "Success from Directory B");

    zip.Save("file.zip");
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I add another folder called `B` in the `Root` folder , such that the `Root` folder contains both `A` and `B` ?? and `B` is not inside folder `A` , it should be a separate folder like `A` .

Comment: Ok, will try and get back to you, ThankYou !

Comment: Ok, I want to dynamically add `A` and `B` to the `Root` , in short , I do not want to use `AddEntry` ,  I want something like  `zip.AddDirectoryByName(${targetDirectory}+"A")` , (because I am using a loop to dynamically create folders in the `Root` depending on a condition !!

Comment: Hi Vanna, ThankYou so much, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: Hi Vanna, Thanks a lot,  I did a little change in your code as per my requirement and tried and it worked like a charm !!!!!!!!!!!